# Adding extra menu in twig template symfony 2.5.3

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony-2.5

I am a Symfony beginner my approach might not be the right way to do things so please help me what am i doing wrong. In my `base.html.twig` i am including a 'menu template' `{% include'::menu.html.twig' %}` This holds all the default top menu items which is working fine.

Now what i am trying to do is on a `about` page I need additional menu option called 'Extra', it does appear but not as a part of a menu. I thought if you call `parent()` this should work just like when you are trying to add extra css or js files using `parent`

This is what my `about.html.twig` looks like

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block topmenu %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <li><a href="">Extra</a></li>
    {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
This is body
{% endblock %}
```

And this is what I see in browser, the menu option **Extra** needs to be the part of rest of the menu

I will really appreciate any assistance here.
[image]

This is what my `menu.html.twig` looks like

```
{% block topmenu %}
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing without code, but I don't think your topmenu block only contains the `<li>` elements, but the whole top bar. So essentially you're starting a new list with your new li.

Comment: you are correct, i am using twitter bootstrap 3 so the `menu.html.twig` contains the `<header>`

Comment: Then you'll need to add a new block that only contains the list items, so you can extend it in your templates with new menuitems.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code of `menu.html.twig` if that helps better understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add an extra line to your template on specific routes, you should make a condition on that route to display this extra menu :

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'my_route' %}
                    <li><a href="">Extra</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```